# Solving integral $\int{\frac{dx}{x^2+ax+4}}$ with assumptions

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

> Solve the following integral for the given cases:
> $$\int{\frac{dx}{x^2+ax+4}},\space\rm{if}\space|a|\lt4$$
> $$\int{\frac{dx}{x^2+ax+4}},\space\rm{if}\space|a|\ge4$$

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I didn't quite understand how those assumptions are supposed to change the final result.

My first attempt was to solve it ignoring the assumptions, so I got this:

$$\frac{2\arctan(\frac{a+2x}{\sqrt{16-a^2}})}{\sqrt{16-a^2}}$$

By looking at it, I can tell that the assumption $|a|\ge4$ would imply in a division by zero and square roots from negative values, but that's all I can see here.

It seems that the assumptions should be used during the integral resolution to lead to different results, but I'm not getting how.

Another information that may be relevant is that $x^2+ax+4$ becomes irreducible when $|a|\lt4$

Comment: "but that's all I can see here": isn't this more than sufficient ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, that was my first thought, but after talking to my professor, his expectation was that we could find different results based on those assumptions.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me. Isn't a square root of a negative a sufficient reason to question your resolution and fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

Note
$$I=\int{\frac{dx}{x^2+ax+4}}= \int{\frac{dx}{(x+\frac a2)^2+\frac{16-{a^2}}4}}
$$

For $|a|\lt4$, we have $\frac{16-{a^2}}4\gt 0$ and

$$I = \frac2{\sqrt{16-{a^2}}}\tan^{-1}\frac{2x+a}{ {\sqrt{16-{a^2}}}}+C
$$

For $|a|\gt 4$, we have $\frac{16-{a^2}}4\lt 0$ and

$$I = \frac1{\sqrt{{a^2}-16}}
\ \ln \left|\frac{1-\frac{2x+a}{\sqrt{a^2-16}}}{1+\frac{2x+a}{\sqrt{a^2-16}} {}}\right| +C
$$

For $|a|=4$, we have

$$I = \int\frac{dx }{(x\pm 2)^2}= -\frac1{x\pm 2}+C
$$

Comment: Hi @quanto, thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining what happened on the second case where `|a| > 4`? Why `(16-a^2)/4 < 0` is changing the final result?

Comment: @TúlioHoffimann - Note $\int\frac{dt}{t^2-b^2}= \frac1{2b} \int (\frac1{t-b}- \frac1{t+b} )dt = \frac1{2b}\ln\frac{t/b-1}{t/b+1}$

Answer (score 1):

This change in behavior is explained by the real or complex nature of the roots of the denominator. By a linear transform, the two cases can be reduced to the forms

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\pm1}$$ and you can't get rid of the sign, because of these roots.

The antiderivatives are respectively

$$\arctan(x)$$ and $$\text{artanh}(x).$$

Notice the relation via imaginary numbers,

$$\arctan(ix)=i\text{ artanh}(x).$$